# How do you recall a function to return another value?

Tags: vb.net, function, boolean

How do you recall a boolean function to return another value in VB.NET?

So first time round its true, but then an event happens which should make it false, however the function doesn't repeat to honour this.

I've tried calling the function by name where I want it to repeat however this didn't work.

As asked for, here is a small example:

```
   Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
           Dim 1 As String = comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem
'What I've tried:
           Call CallByName(Me, AlreadyInListbox(), vbMethod, e)
           If AlreadyInListbox() = True Then
            MsgBox("Its already in there")
           End If
           If AlreadyInListbox() = False Then
               ListBox1.Items.Add(comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem)
           End If

       End Sub

    Function AlreadyInListbox() As Boolean
        For Each item In ListBox1.Items
            If item.Contains(comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

So each time the button is clicked, I want the function to reiterate the For Loop to maybe produce another value if appropriate.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  It would be very helpful if you could post as small of an example as is possible which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `AlreadyInListbox` can be simplified:

```
Function AlreadyInListbox() As Boolean

   Return ListBox1.Items.Contains(comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem)

End Function
```

there is no need to loop thru each item since the item collection can answer the question.  Given its new simplicity, it need not exist.

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click

       ' WHAT????  this cant compile. so this isnt real code
       'Dim 1 As String = comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem

       ' tell us why this wont work.  is there an error?
       If AlreadyInListbox()  Then
            MsgBox("Its already in there")
       ELse
           ListBox1.Items.Add(comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem)
       End If

End Sub
```

But, given the new simplicity, this will work:

```
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem) Then
     MsgBox("Its already in there")
Else
     ListBox1.Items.Add(comboboxSelectGroup.SelectedItem)
End If
```

I dont know what you mean by "repeating" a function, as long as they are in `scope`, they are infinitely reusable.